# iPad 2 certain emails received are gibberish

Tags: ipad, email

Why are some emails I send to others received in gibberish- containing dozens of extra characters? What settings can I change to prevent this?

Comment: What application(s) are your recipients using to read your emails?

Comment: ... I'm assuming your using Apple Mail to send from your iPad as well.  Is this correct?

Comment: Are all others receiving emails like this?  What operating system and email clients are these others using?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you using all your providers default email settings

Is it only on new email ; or on forwarded ones as well?